# Increment letters in javascript

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm trying to increment a letter used in a recurring function, This function is called every time a user selects another possible end point. However it keeps using the name B, is there a way to increment it each time?

```
var tempEnd = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + 1);

/* create end point */
function end_point(t) {
    calculate_start = false;
    name = tempEnd;
    marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(coordinate, {
        text: name,
        draggable: true,
        e_num: end_ar.length
    });
    marker.addListener("drag", dragAndDrop, true);
    marker.addListener("dragend", dragAndDrop, false);
    document.getElementById("points").style.display = 'none';
    map.objects.add(marker);
    if (t == true) {
        map.zoomTo(map.getBoundingBox());
    }
    end_ar.push(coordinate);
    createTable();
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace it with

```
var tempEnd='A';
tempEnd = String.fromCharCode(tempend.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
```

Comment: That gives me the same results

Comment: Well you'd have to run `tempEnd = String.fromCharCode(tempend.charCodeAt(0) + 1);` every time you wanted to increment it

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use tempEnd to increment, in which case you could store name externally and then call it each time you want to increment:

```
//store name
var name = "A"
//create tempEnd incrementation
function tempEnd(str){
    var number = 1;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(0) + number);
    number++;
    return letter;
}

//call name on tempEnd
name=tempEnd(name);
name=tempEnd(name);
//name is now "C"
```